# Reflection in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

This line of code:

```
db.Set<T>().Max(d => d.GetType().GetProperty("DateTimePropertyName").GetValue(d))
```

causes this exception:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object GetValue(System.Object)' method
```

How do I make it work?

Comment: I think it will not work because you are querying a DB, which won'T support GetType()...

Comment: Is it important that the calculation is performed server side? You are basically asking for the server to calculate something that LinqToEntities cannot communicate to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default it assumes that you pass `Expression<Func<T,TResult>>`, but what you need is to pass `Func<T,TResult>`:

```
Func<T, object> f = p => p.GetType().GetProperty("DateTimePropertyName").GetValue(p); 
_context.Set<T>().Max(f);
```

It comes from IEnumerable, so it will hit performance if you table is large

Answer (score 1):

Your trying to run c# code that's suppose to get translated into SQL somehow and can't.

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/246861/LINQ-to-Entities-Basic-Concepts-and-Features) is a good guide to start with.

You have two options:

1.Fetch the data from the DB and go through it with LINQ to Objects - Probally the easiest and not the best way to do things since some queries can return large collections.

2.Try to find a better way to do what you are doing. Why would you want this reflection code to run? What's the purpose? Is the DateTimePropertyName non public? If so why? Otherwise something like this should work:

```
db.Set<T>().Max(d => d.DateTimePropertyName);
```

Comment: It's a generic class that and I need to do it on server-side.

Comment: You should remove "== Something", and perhaps give some code in 1. Otherwise, good answer. +1

Comment: @MarkusJohnsson - Youre right..I did the == Something by mistake :)